# Getting single report from openvas using omp xml command with filter

Tags: openvas

I'm trying to get single report from openvas using omp cli with filter option as shown below:

```
--xml=<get_reports report_id="8b8750e2-ecd0-4234-86d5-09ba22136b81" format_id="c402cc3e-b531-11e1-9163-406186ea4fc5" filter="overrides=1,levels=hml,notes=1,min_qod=70,autofp=0"/>
```

but in the report it's not taking effect. I'm always getting same report irrespective of what levels(hmlgd) I mention and report always contain

```
Information on overrides is included in the report.
Notes are included in the report.
This report might not show details of all issues that were found.
Issues with the threat level High are not shown.
Issues with the threat level Medium are not shown.
Issues with the threat level Low are not shown.
Issues with the threat level Log are not shown.
Issues with the threat level Debug are not shown.
Issues with the threat level False Positive are not shown.
Only results with a minimum QoD of 70 are shown.
```

I'm just trying to get a single report which should contain only high, medium and low vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

The filter must be listed without commas

```
filter="overrides=1 levels=hml notes=1 min_qod=70 autofp=0"
```